# How to geocode addresses that are outside Address Ranges of source layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geocoding, tiger, address

Im using TIGER lines to geocode a table of addresses. Say for instance the address range for a street is 1100-1200. What would be the best way to match an address such as 1094?

Comment: What software or web service are you using?

Comment: Can you give us a full example - a full address.

Comment: Creating my own locators using TIGER lines with ArcInfo 10.1

Comment: something like 1050 200th Ave, whereas the address range for 200th Ave is like 1052-1100.

Comment: Based on your comment below, it seems like the TIGER data is not as complete as you might need.  What is your area of interest?  Is there a regional dataset available that is more complete?

Comment: There should be a way to get it to default to streetname -- at least place it on the street -- with a composite locator (and there are other methods). I know you can do this and default to zipcode centroids, etc. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00250000003r000000.htm

Answer (score 3):

> Address locator Style field, select “US Address Dual Ranges.” For
>   Reference Data, select “Streets” from the drop-down menu. In the Field
>   Map area, make sure that every field with an asterisk has an entry
>   under “Alias Name.” The field for Street Name should be assigned to
>   FULLNAME.

[image]

source:
http://guides.library.upenn.edu/content.php?pid=334808&sid=2743280

Comment: Yea that's what I do. I guess the new addresses i'm trying to geocode aren't included in the TIGER lines.

Comment: The reason the examples you gave above are not matching is because they are outside the ranges, like you specified.  The way you would have to locate those is using the manual geocoding process.  The other option is to find a dataset that has a wider range of addresses for each street.